# How do I specify na_values in pandas using read_sql?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a pandas dataframe from a sql table. I read in the data using `data=pd.read_sql(query,con=con)`, and this works just fine. However, I wish to set which type of elements in the data frame is NaN. When reading a csv, this can be set using `pd.read_csv('file.csv',na_values=['',[]'])`. Is there a similar flag available using read_sql?

Comment: Not according to the docs:  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html

Answer (score 4):

There is no such parameter because pandas/numpy `NaN` corresponds `NULL` (in the database), so there is one to one relation.

But if you want to replace other values with NaNs you can do it this way:

```
df = df.replace(['', 'null'], [np.nan, np.nan])
```

Comment: I think this is false. If the result of your query has a column that contains only `NULL` (from the SQL, not yet in anything python) than the resulting DataFrame column will have dtype==object and will be all `None`.

This can give surprising results when you expect your data to be a float instead.

Answer (score 0):

Best to specify the dtype. For strings, leverage the new `'string'` dtype in pandas, rather than `Object` dtype, as there is better handling between other libraries like arrow and polars. Using `str` returns an `Object` dtype which leads to "None"s in arrow and polars.

```py
df = pd.read_sql_query("""SELECT NULL AS CUR UNION SELECT 'EUR'""", con=connection_uri, dtype={'CUR': 'string'})
df.dtypes
# CUR string
# create pyarrow table from pandas
import pyarrow as pa
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
pq.write_table(table, 'test.parquet')
# pyarrow.Table
# CUR: string
# CUR: [[null,"EUR"]]
import polars as pl
pl.read_parquet('test.parquet')
# CUR
# str
# null
# "EUR"
```